# How do I select short Cisco interface names with RegEx in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to select shortened Cisco interface names as shown below, from CDP as well as show mac address-table output using Python with RegEx.

I have tried a RegEx tester and Gig\s?\d+(/\d+)* seems to work great, but it does not work in my Python code. It seems a little lacking, even when I try to escape the forward-slash, which I get varying opinions on via RegEx documentation.

DEVICENAME       Gig 2/0/45        136              R T   AIR-CAP35 Gig 0

DEVICENAME       Gig 2/0/47        158              R T   AIR-CAP35 Gig 0

DEVICENAME       Gig 1/0/1         174             R S I  CISCO2921 Gig 0/1

DEVICENAME       Gig 3/0/1         151             R S I  CISCO2921 Gig 0/1

For inputs such as Gig 3/0/1 above I get matches that look like /1, /2, etc. Please help with what I am missing and an explanation of what Python is doing to my RegEx would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried various RegEx such as Gig\s?\d+ and it starts to work, but won't capture the extended name. When I start adding on, such as Gig\s?\d+/\d+/\d+ it works fantastic, but it will not handle names without 3 sets of numbers, such as on a 4500 where they will be more like Gig 4/30. When I add the grouping to optionally add the /\d+ for interfaces further down in a line-card stack, such as on a 3750 the RegEx quickly falls apart between what I can validate in a tester vs. through Python.

If I double-group the last part such as Gig\s?\d+((/\d+)*) it no longer captures the first part, which is really throwing me off.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you use `re.findall` function. NOte that `re.findall` gives the first preference to groups. If no groups are present, then only it would return the matches. So i suggest you to turn the capturing group present in your regex to non-capturing group.

```
r'Gig\s?\d+(?:/\d+)*'
```

Code:

```
>>> s = """DEVICENAME Gig 2/0/45 136 R T AIR-CAP35 Gig 0

DEVICENAME Gig 2/0/47 158 R T AIR-CAP35 Gig 0

DEVICENAME Gig 1/0/1 174 R S I CISCO2921 Gig 0/1

DEVICENAME Gig 3/0/1 151 R S I CISCO2921 Gig 0/1"""
>>> re.findall(r'Gig\s?\d+(?:/\d+)*', s)
['Gig 2/0/45', 'Gig 0', 'Gig 2/0/47', 'Gig 0', 'Gig 1/0/1', 'Gig 0/1', 'Gig 3/0/1', 'Gig 0/1']
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that about re.findall. I had tried a leading ? in the group to make it a (passive?) group but got an error. I will look into what the ?: does.

Comment: `(?:...)` called non-capturing group. error? please post that error.

Answer (score 0):

If all your lines are in similar order you can split:

```
s = "DEVICENAME Gig 3/0/1 151 R S I CISCO2921 Gig 0/1"
spl = s.split()
print(" ".join(spl[1:3])," ".join(spl[-2:]))
Gig 3/0/1 Gig 0/1


s = """DEVICENAME Gig 2/0/45 136 R T AIR-CAP35 Gig 0
DEVICENAME Gig 2/0/47 158 R T AIR-CAP35 Gig 0
DEVICENAME Gig 1/0/1 174 R S I CISCO2921 Gig 0/1
DEVICENAME Gig 3/0/1 151 R S I CISCO2921 Gig 0/1"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    spl = line.split()
    dev1, dev2  =" ".join(spl[1:3])," ".join(spl[-2:])
    print(dev1, dev2)

Gig 2/0/45 Gig 0
Gig 2/0/47 Gig 0
Gig 1/0/1 Gig 0/1
Gig 3/0/1 Gig 0/1
```